# Have Matlab's "readtable" recognize column headings?

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I have the following CSV file with column headings on line 1:

```
Test.csv
--------
Prj  , Cap
A    ,  1
A    ,  2
H    ,  4
H    ,  5
```

I tried to read this into a table, but I'm having trouble making `readtable` recognize the column headings on line 1:

```
readtable( 'Test.csv' , ...
           delimitedTextImportOptions( 'VariableNamesLine' , 1 ) )

Var1     ExtraVar1
_____    _________
'Prj'     ' Cap'  
'A'       '  1'   
'A'       '  2'   
'H'       '  4'   
'H'       '  5'
```

**What am I misunderstanding about the `VariableNamesLine` parameter?**

I am using Matlab 2019a.  `doc delimitedTextImportOptions` shows it as being introduced in Matlab 2016b, and I am running Matlab 2019a.

**Troubleshooting steps**

Here is the `delimitedTextImportOptions` object:

```
dtio = delimitedTextImportOptions( 'VariableNamesLine' , 1)

     DelimitedTextImportOptions with properties:
      Format Properties:
                       Delimiter: {','}
                      Whitespace: '\b\t '
                      LineEnding: {'\n'  '\r'  '\r\n'}
                    CommentStyle: {}
       ConsecutiveDelimitersRule: 'split'
           LeadingDelimitersRule: 'keep'
                   EmptyLineRule: 'skip'
                        Encoding: 'system'
      Replacement Properties:
                     MissingRule: 'fill'
                 ImportErrorRule: 'fill'
                ExtraColumnsRule: 'addvars'
      Variable Import Properties: Set types by name using setvartype
                   VariableNames: {'Var1'}
                   VariableTypes: {'char'}
           SelectedVariableNames: {'Var1'}
                 VariableOptions: Show all 1 VariableOptions
      Access VariableOptions sub-properties using setvaropts/getvaropts
      Location Properties:
                       DataLines: [1 Inf]
               VariableNamesLine: 1
                  RowNamesColumn: 0
               VariableUnitsLine: 0
        VariableDescriptionsLine: 0
```

If I specify `ReadVariableNames` as true, only the *first* column heading is recognized.  And it still gets repeated in the data.

```
readtable( 'Test.csv' , dtio , 'ReadVariableNames',true )

     Prj     ExtraVar1
    _____    _________
    'Prj'     ' Cap'
    'A'       '  1'
    'A'       '  2'
    'H'       '  4'
    'H'       '  5'
```

I can avoid having headings read as data by explicitly specifying `DataLines`, but the 2nd column heading is still unread.

```
dtio = delimitedTextImportOptions( ...
  'VariableNamesLine' , 1 , ...
  'DataLines' , [2 Inf] );
readtable( 'Test.csv' , dtio , 'ReadVariableNames',true )

Prj    ExtraVar1
___    _________
'A'      '  1'
'A'      '  2'
'H'      '  4'
'H'      '  5'
```

Oddly, the `DataLines` specification is ignored if I additionally unset any preconceived `VariableNames`:

```
dtio = delimitedTextImportOptions( ...
  'VariableNamesLine' , 1 , ...
  'DataLines' , [2 Inf] , ...
   'VariableNames' , {} );
readtable( 'Test.csv' , dtio , 'ReadVariableNames',true )

    ExtraVar1    ExtraVar2
    _________    _________
     'Prj  '      ' Cap'
     'A    '      '  1'
     'A    '      '  2'
     'H    '      '  4'
     'H    '      '  5'
```

Following suggestions in the responses, I tried the default `readtable` options.  Unfortunately, this did not recognize `,` as a delimiter:

```
readtable('Test.csv')

Warning: Table variable names were modified to make them valid MATLAB identifiers. The original names are saved in the VariableDescriptions property. 

    Prj    x_     Cap
    ___    ___    ___
    'A'    ','     1 
    'A'    ','     2 
    'H'    ','     4 
    'H'    ','     5
```

Using a format string helps recognition of the column heading line, but white space around the delimiters is kept for the string columns:

```
readtable('Test.csv', 'Format', '%s%u')

      Prj      Cap
    _______    ___
    'A    '     1 
    'A    '     2 
    'H    '     4 
    'H    '     5
```

I get the same results regardless of whether `Test.csv` has Unix or DOS line endings.

I will continue to investigate, read, and experiment.

P.S. Very odd, but the Matlab Answers forum at Matlab Central won't let me post this question (prior to coming here).  I can enter text for the subject heading, but no insertion point appears in the message body no matter how much I click.  It happens using both Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in R2020a, you can be straightforward and use

```
readtable('Test.csv')
```

The command automatically instructs to skip the first line of headers. The data type for each column will be inferred from the data itself.

Alternatively, you could specify the data type of each column by using command option `'Format'`:

```
readtable('Test.csv', 'Format', '%s%u')
```

This will read your first column as a string and the second as an unsigned integer (for signed integer use `%i`).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm running Matlab 2019a.  I've added the results of experimenting with your code patterns.  It doesn't quite work for me.  I am continuing to experiment.

Comment: I found a fix for the wrinkle I encountered in using `tTest=readtable('Test.csv', 'Format', '%s%u')`.  The string variable/column data retained the trailing spaces that preceded the delimiter, as now described in my posted question.  The affected column was `tTest.Prj`.  The fix was `tTest.Prj=categorical(tTest.Prj)`.

Comment: The more direct way to deal with this seems to be to somehow set `WhitespaceRule` to `trim`, but `WhitespaceRule` is not a property of the object returned by `delimitedTextImportOptions`. For Matlab 2019's `doc`, it shows up in `detectImportOptions`, but isn't explained. It is explained in `setvaropts`, which is applied to the object returned by `detectImportOptions`. Both imply that the import process needs to be explored in order to use `WhitespaceRule`. In particular, the variables/columns need to be preliminarily identified and characterized. That's way more complicated than I want.

Comment: With all this tinkering you are going down a rabbit hole ... I reckon updating to the current version may be the best option for you

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not my decision.  It's a matter of dollars, for which there are always conflicting demands.  These days, it's getting harder because of the competing analysis environments.

Comment: I understand. I am only familiar with academic licenses allowing automatic updates when the new version is out.